# Pass column as number into separate R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

Is it possible to pass `col` variable as number into `separate` function?

From `?separate` `col` is define as `Bare column name.`

```
Dataframe <- data.frame(Time = rep("1:00 AM", times = 20), Place = rep("Wawa", times = 20))
Dataframe2 <- data.frame(Time2 = rep("1:00 AM", times = 20), Place = rep("Wawa", times = 20))
Data <- list(Dataframe , Dataframe2)

Dataframe %>% separate(col = Time, into = c("col_name_1NEW", "col_name_2NEW"), sep =" ") #works

Dataframe2 %>% separate(col = Time2, into = c("col_name_1NEW", "col_name_2NEW"), sep =" ") #works

for(i in 1:length(Data)){
Data[[i]] %>% separate(col = Time, into = c("col_name_1NEW", "col_name_2NEW"), sep =" ")
} #returns error because of wrong colum name for Data[[2]]
```

I would like to make it more universal by giving `col` argument as column number not name like:

```
for(i in 1:length(Data)){
    Data[[i]] %>% separate(col = 1, into = c("col_name_1NEW", "col_name_2NEW"), sep =" ")
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `separate_` to pass column names as string:

```
lapply(Data, function(i){
  separate_(i, col = colnames(i)[1],
            into = c("col_name_1NEW", "col_name_2NEW"),
            sep = " ")
  })
```

Comment: Can I use it with `%>%` ?

Comment: It is just one function, but if you need then, `i %>% separate_(col = colnames(i)[1], ... `

Comment: I have got an error `Error in UseMethod("separate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'separate_' applied to an object of class "character"`

Comment: @piotr with your example data, my solution works. Error says you are passing character to separate, where it requires a dataframe.